# Problems defining value of css attribute using .css() with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a function that will change the color of a span from black to a random color from a list of colors I have defined. My problem seems to be in the .css("color", variableName) part. I think I may be doing my syntax wrong.
( http://jsfiddle.net/crismanNoble/8gM76/ )

```
$(".randomRoll")
    .mouseover(function() {
               var colors = ["6F216C", "F34B0D", "C50102", "5DA537", "F1D81B"];
               var pick = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
               var colorN = colors[pick];
               $(this).css("color", colorN); 
               //alert(colorN);
               })
    .mouseout(function() {
              $(this).css('color','black');
    });
```

Comment: `$(this).css("color","#" + colorN);` would do the trick ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add a hash (#) in front of any hex values you use in CSS.
`$(this).css("color","#"+colorN);`

or better yet add them in your colors array.

Comment: Everyone looks over small errors such as those once in a while :) @Derek Thanks, edited.

Comment: That's not a bracket, it's a hash. Brackets are either square `[]` or curly `{}`. :)